# Travis CI won't install eventmachine?

Tags: ruby, travis-ci

I'm just getting started with CI on my open-source project, and it's all going swimmingly, however Travis is continually failing when it gets to pieces of code that require `eventmachine`. `Eventmachine` is specified in the gemspec as both runtime and development dependency (same as `wisper`), but Travis will not install `Eventmachine`, causing every build to fail - however, it *does* install `wisper`. What's going on? :(

[Most recent build that failed](https://travis-ci.org/DanPantry/angler/jobs/20768904)

**GemSpec Dependencies**

..

```
  spec.add_development_dependency 'bundler', '~> 1.5'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'rake'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'rspec', '~> 2.4'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'wisper'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'eventmachine'

  spec.add_runtime_dependency 'wisper'
  spec.add_runtime_dependency 'eventmachine'
```

**Travis YML**

```
rvm:
  - 1.9.3
  # we don't support 1.9.2
  # - 1.9.2
  - jruby
  - rbx

script: "bundle exec rake"
```

**Rake default task**

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new :spec
task :default => :spec
```

**Log**

```
$ gem --version
2.2.2
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.5.3
Applying fix for NPM certificates
install
$ bundle install --deployment
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing rake (10.1.1)
Installing wisper (1.3.0)
angler at /home/travis/build/DanPantry/angler did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  duplicate dependency on wisper (>= 0), (>= 0) use:
    add_runtime_dependency 'wisper', '>= 0', '>= 0'
Using angler (0.0.1) from source at .
Installing timers (1.1.0)
Installing celluloid (0.15.2)
Installing nio4r (1.0.0)
Installing celluloid-io (0.15.0)
Installing diff-lcs (1.2.5)
Installing formatador (0.2.4)
Installing rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
Installing rb-inotify (0.9.3)
Installing listen (2.7.1)
Installing lumberjack (1.0.4)
Installing thor (0.18.1)
Installing guard (2.5.1)
Using bundler (1.5.3)
Installing guard-bundler (2.0.0)
Installing rspec-core (2.14.8)
Installing rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
Installing rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
Installing rspec (2.14.1)
Installing guard-rspec (4.2.8)
Cannot write a changed lockfile while frozen.
Your bundle is complete!
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
$ bundle exec rake
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/remote_spec.rb
/home/travis/build/DanPantry/angler/lib/angler.rb:5:in `require': cannot load such file -- eventmachine (LoadError)
```

NOTE: Even without add_runtime_dependency, Travis just won't install EventMachine.

Answer (score 0):

The important part of your log is this

```
angler at /home/travis/build/DanPantry/angler did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  duplicate dependency on wisper (>= 0), (>= 0) use:
    add_runtime_dependency 'wisper', '>= 0', '>= 0'
```

Fix your gemspec, then bundler can install gems specified there. I simple solution would be to remove the development dependency to wisper and rely solely on the runtime_dependency for it.

Comment: Except, I did do this, and it still didn't work. See the previous builds